# flex-wrap: wrap; does not work correctly with mutltiple flex-boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a DIV with two flex-boxes, the DIV itself is also a flex-box. I want both flex-boxes to wrap; therefore, I assigned `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent DIV. However, this behaves correctly until the flex box has multiple lines.

I'll try to explain it with images:

The following images show the behavior I want everywhere. All the boxes wrap.
[image]

However, when I add multiple DIV's with the class `.book` so that the browser needs multiple lines to display it, the wanted behavior vanishes. The item with the big plus sign and the id `#add-book` takes up a whole new line. However, I want it to wrap.
[image]

This is the HTML code, every book/box added, is another DIV in the DIV[id="added-books"] with the class of `.book`. This code would be displayed as shown in the first screenshot. I've just duplicated the DIV with the class of `.book` and the ID of `#Second Book` five times.

```css
#books,
#added-books {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book,
#add-book {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 20em;
  width: 13em;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.book hr {
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.book-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.book-author {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.book-pages {
  font-size: xx-small;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#add-book {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#add-book #plus {
  font-size: 10em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="books">
  <div id="added-books">
    <div id="The Hobbit" class="book">
      <p class="book-title">The Hobbit</p>
      <hr>
      <p class="book-author">by J.R.R. Tolkien</p>
      <p class="book-pages">295 pages</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Second Book" class="book">
      <p class="book-title">Second Book</p>
      <hr>
      <p class="book-author">by any author</p>
      <p class="book-pages">296 pages</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="add-book">
    <p id="plus">+</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that, if I have multiple lines of book/boxes/divs, the plus-sign DIV with the id of `#add-book` wraps as in the first screenshot? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought that flex-wrap would prevent each flex-item from taking one whole line.? I want to achieve, that the plus-sign container is on the same line as the Second Book container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the books and add-book to all wrap together, they must participate in the same flexbox.

This is what `display:contents` was designed for - to remove intermediate boxes from the box tree, so that elements at lower levels of the DOM could participate in the same flexbox or grid. Here, the box to be removed is the one that would otherwise be generated by the #added-books element.

So

```css
#added-books {
  display:contents;
}

#books {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.book, #add-book{
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    height: 20em;
    width: 13em;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1em;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.book hr {
    border: none;
    background-color: black;
    width: 80%;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.book-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.book-author {
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;

    font-size: smaller;
}

.book-pages {
    font-size: xx-small;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#add-book {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#add-book #plus {
    font-size: 10em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="books">
    <div id="added-books">
        <div id="TheHobbit" class="book">
            <p class="book-title">The Hobbit</p>
            <hr>
            <p class="book-author">by J.R.R. Tolkien</p>
            <p class="book-pages">295 pages</p>
        </div>

        <div id="SecondBook" class="book">
            <p class="book-title">Second Book</p>
            <hr>
            <p class="book-author">by any author</p>
            <p class="book-pages">296 pages</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ThirdBook" class="book">
            <p class="book-title">Third Book</p>
            <hr>
            <p class="book-author">by any author</p>
            <p class="book-pages">296 pages</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="add-book">
        <p id="plus">+</p>
    </div>
</div>
```